# In a table if td border is not set then the background image displays in firefox but not in google and safari

Tags: html, css

I am beginner in web page development so I don't have any knowlede about which things one should keep in mind while developing webpage as different browser have different approach of displaying the webpage. So please help me to know the proper way to develop the web page.

Right now i am facing a problem :

In the table if 'td' border is not set then the background image displayed in `firefox` but not in `chrome` and `safari` and if set then it display in `chrome`, `safari` and `firefox`.

Why?

Comment: Can u show some HTML/CSS code? And if possible - demo the issue at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: <html>
 <body>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td  style="background-image:url('images/logo1.jpg');border:0px solid orange;">
      
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: so when i put 0px in border then the background image display in firefox but not in google and safari
and when i put 1px solid then background image display in all three browser